# Equating an Input to an integer that is included in an arraylist

Tags: java, arraylist

I am learning the arrays and arraylist but how can i compare an integer input to an interger that is in arraylist.
What can i use to initialize my input to equate to the first 10 integers in the arraylist.

```
    ArrayList<Integer> a1 = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    for (int x=1;x<=20;x++){
    a1.add(x);
    }
    Collections.shuffle(a1);
    System.out.println(a1);
    a1.get(0);
    for(int z = 0;z<=9;z++){
    System.out.print( a1.get(z)+ "\t");
    }
    int Input1=Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter the Card Number: "));
    for(int i=0;i<=9;i++){
    if(Input1==a1.get(i))
        System.out.println("Good");

    }
```

Comment: Could you include code you've attempted to solve your problem please. Also, please format your for loops properly with indentation. I know they're single line loops but including the `{ }` would make it a lot more readable for people trying help you.

Comment: @d_ominic i have tried using an if statement but i do not know what is the syntax on to compare the input to the integer inside the arraylist

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, I recommend you program to the `List` interface (instead of the `ArrayList` implementation). Next, by convention, Java variable names start with a lower case letter (`input1` instead of `Input1`). Finally, you could use [`List.contains(Object)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html#contains%28java.lang.Object%29). Something like,

```
List<Integer> a1 = new ArrayList<>();
for (int x = 1; x <= 20; x++) {
    a1.add(x);
}
Collections.shuffle(a1);
int input1 = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane
        .showInputDialog("Enter the Card Number: "));
System.out.println(a1.contains(input1));
```

**Note**: The above will display true for any value `1` to `20` inclusive (becuase that is what has been added to the `List`).

#### First ten values

In response to your comment,

> I only need to equate it to the first 10 integer.

The Javadoc for [`List.subList(int, int)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html#subList%28int,%20int%29) reads (in part)

> Returns a view of the portion of this list between the specified `fromIndex`, inclusive, and `toIndex`, exclusive. (If `fromIndex` and `toIndex` are equal, the returned list is empty.) The returned list is backed by this list

And you might use it like

```
System.out.println(a1.subList(0, 10).contains(input1));
```

Comment: It does the trick but it equates the input to the whole interger inside that list. I only need to equate it to the first 10 integer.

Comment: well that is the solution applicable to my problem. thanks a lot